# How to play a sound, when i click a button or link in a browser,

Tags: php, html

how to play a sound file, when i click a link or button in my web page , I also need place more than one link or button each one have different sound file.

actually i did this using BGSOUND tag it works only in IE,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Step 1**: download the 'standalone' version of [audio player](http://wpaudioplayer.com/download/)

**Step 2**: include player's JS to your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="audio-player.js"></script>
```

**Step 3**: setup player and implement functions to embed player for each file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    AudioPlayer.setup("player.swf", {  
        width: 290
    });

    function moo() {
        AudioPlayer.embed("player", {soundFile: "moo.mp3", autostart: 'yes'});  
    }

    function foo() {
        AudioPlayer.embed("player", {soundFile: "foo.mp3", autostart: 'yes'});  
    }
</script>
```

**Step 4**: create some element with `id = player` (or whatever you've specified):

```
<div id="player"></div><br />
```

**Step 5**: provide 'switchers' for your audio files:

```
<a href="#" onClick="moo();">play file 1</a><br />
<a href="#" onClick="foo();">play file 2</a>
```

You should end with something like this:

```
<html>  
    <head>  
        <title>Your website</title>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="audio-player.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript">  
            AudioPlayer.setup("player.swf", {  
                width: 290
            });

            function moo() {
                AudioPlayer.embed("player", {soundFile: "moo.mp3", autostart: 'yes'});  
            }

            function foo() {
                AudioPlayer.embed("player", {soundFile: "foo.mp3", autostart: 'yes'});  
            }
        </script>    
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <div id="player"></div><br />
        <a href="#" onClick="moo();">play file 1</a><br />
        <a href="#" onClick="foo();">play file 2</a>
    </body>  
</html>
```

P.S.: [here](http://wpaudioplayer.com/standalone/) are some docs on player's options you could pass with `.embed()` or `.setup()` functions

Comment: well, the code i've shown is not a `wordpress-one` nor a `wordpress-only` =) That's why i noticed to download a **standalone** version of player ;)

Comment: you can do the same thing with the html5 sound api, this is only needed if you want to support all browsers im guessing

Comment: Yeah, HTML5 is good enough, except of its browser requirements =)

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you just link to the sound file on the web app?

eg, something like this:

```
<a href="/pathtosound/sound.mp3">Click here to play a sound</a>
```

Comment: thanks marty., when using A tag, some browser download the file instad of playing,

Comment: ok then with html5 you can access the audio api directly in javascript. eg. var sound = new Audio("file.mp3");
sound.play(); - so basically you would be capturing the button/link event in javascript and running javascript code like this to play the sound. only works with html5 browsers tho, but most modern browsers support it :) - for browsers that dont support it you can show a static link instead.